# PHP search array fastest way (alphabetic narrowing down implemented)?

Tags: php

I have an multidim. array with >2000 Values.

Which simple way is the most efficient to search a value within.

**What i am especially curious about is if  array_search() uses alphabetic narrowing down to be more efficient (there is no parameter though to indicate if alphanumeric).**

```
$_array = ["abidabi", "beda", "cedi", "zamibula"];
$_target = "zamibula";

foreach($_array as $val)
{
    if ($val == $_target)
    {
        echo $val;
    }
```

vs.

```
echo $_array[array_search('zamibula', $_array)];
```

for sure my actual code is very more complicated (json, multidimensional array with massive data to populate an INPUT->SELECT->OPTIONS), so it already lags browserside.

What are your thoughts on the alphabetical search? Can i structure the data somehow to make it less consuming :)?

thanks

Comment: >> Which simple way is the most efficient to search a value within.  Using a database?

Comment: Using in_array, would be your best bet on arrays > 1000. See: https://gist.github.com/ksimka/21a6ff74b41451c430e8

Answer (score 0):

If all the values in the array are unique, than the fastest way is to switch values to keys and then call `isset` like so:

```php
$_array = ["abidabi", "beda", "cedi", "zamibula"];
$_target = "zamibula";

$indexed = array_flip($_array);
var_dump(isset($indexed[$_target]));
```

This is almost constantly fast no matter the size of an array.